# How to control the state of GPIO pins on ESP32 Camera from an external python script?

Tags: esp32, python, gpio

I am currently working on a project that detects specific objects in a video stream. If a particular object is detected, an alarm of some sort will be rung. An HTML page will display the object detection output and the name of the object detected. I have used flask with python for the HTML page. The video from the ESP32 Camera is given to a python script through a URL; then, the output will be displayed on the HTML page. I am not using the camera webserver rather using a flask web app.
I have completed the object detection part and the object detection output successfully. But I can't seem to figure out a way to control the alarm system attached to the ESP32-Cam through the python script.
This is my python code

```
from pickletools import read_uint1
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
import cvzone


#url = 'C:/Users/Mukesh/Downloads/videoplayback.mp4'
url = '192.168.35.7:81/stream'

classNames = []
classFile = 'C:/Users/Mukesh/Desktop/Mini Project/Code/AIM/coco.names'
with open(classFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().split('\n')
configPath = 'C:/Users/Mukesh/Desktop/Mini Project/Code/AIM/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = "C:/Users/Mukesh/Desktop/Mini Project/Code/AIM/frozen_inference_graph.pb"
net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)
app = Flask(__name__)
thres = 0.55
nmsThres = 0.2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

def gen_frames():
    while 1:
        isTrue, img = cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        if img is not None:
            classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(
                img, confThreshold=thres, nmsThreshold=nmsThres)
            try:
                for classId, conf, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
                    id = classNames[classId - 1]
                    #Send ID to HTML page
                    print(id)
                    if id=='drone':
                        cvzone.cornerRect(img, box)
                        cv2.putText(img, f'{classNames[classId - 1].upper()} {round(conf * 100, 2)}',
                                (box[0] + 10, box[1] +
                                 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,
                                1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                frame = img
                ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = buffer.tobytes()
                cv2.imshow('',img)
                if cv2.waitKey(20)&0xff==ord(' '):
                    break
                yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                       b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
            except:
                pass
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        else:
            break


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('Home.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
                background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2E3192, #1BFFFF);
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row;
            }

            .booth {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
            }

            .f2 {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column-reverse;
            }

            .f2 .text {
                flex: 0 1 auto;
            }

            .f2 .frame {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
                position: relative;
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column;
            }

            .f2 .frame #click-photo {
                flex: 0 1 auto;
            }

            .f2 .frame #canvas {
                flex: 1 1 auto;
            }

            #canvas {
                background-color: red;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="booth">
            <!--video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay></video-->
            <img id="video" src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="f2">
            <div class="frame">
                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                <button id="click-photo">Click Photo</button>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h2 id="status" src="{{ url_for('obj')}}"></h2>
                <!---Drone status--->
                <h2 id="cam"></h2>
                <!--Camera location-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            let video = document.querySelector("#video");
            let click_button = document.querySelector("#click-photo");
            let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");

            click_button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                console.log(image_data_url);
                //document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = " Drone: detected";
                document.getElementById("cam").innerHTML = "Camera: 1";
            });
            var stop = function () {
                var stream = video.srcObject;
                var tracks = stream.getTracks();
                for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
                    var track = tracks[i];
                    track.stop();
                }
                video.srcObject = null;
            }
            var start = function () {
                var video = document.getElementById('video'),
                    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                        .then(function (stream) {
                            video.srcObject = stream;
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log("Something went wrong!");
                        });
                }
            }
            $(function () {
                start();
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is the ESP32 Camera code

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_timer.h"
#include "img_converters.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "soc/soc.h" //disable brownout problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"  //disable brownout problems
#include "esp_http_server.h"
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
//Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "Mukesh";
const char* password = "qwertyuiop";

#define PART_BOUNDARY "123456789000000000000987654321"

// This project was tested with the AI Thinker Model, M5STACK PSRAM Model and M5STACK WITHOUT PSRAM
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WITHOUT_PSRAM

// Not tested with this model
//#define CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT

#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27

  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       5
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       4
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23

  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WITHOUT_PSRAM)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23

  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM       17
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER)
  #define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
  #define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
  #define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
  #define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
  #define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

  #define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
  #define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
  #define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
  #define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
  #define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
  #define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
  #define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
  #define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
  #define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
  #define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
  #define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22
#else
  #error "Camera model not selected"
#endif
// #define Ser_1 14
// #define Ser_2 15
// #define ser_step 5
// Servo sn1;
// Servo sn2;
// Servo s1;
// Servo s2;
// int pos1=0;
// int pos2=0;

static const char* _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=" PART_BOUNDARY;
static const char* _STREAM_BOUNDARY = "\r\n--" PART_BOUNDARY "\r\n";
static const char* _STREAM_PART = "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: %u\r\n\r\n";

httpd_handle_t stream_httpd = NULL;

static esp_err_t stream_handler(httpd_req_t *req){
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  esp_err_t res = ESP_OK;
  size_t _jpg_buf_len = 0;
  uint8_t * _jpg_buf = NULL;
  char * part_buf[64];

  res = httpd_resp_set_type(req, _STREAM_CONTENT_TYPE);
  if(res != ESP_OK){
    return res;
  }

  while(true){
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    if (!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      res = ESP_FAIL;
    } else {
      if(fb->width > 400){
        if(fb->format != PIXFORMAT_JPEG){
          bool jpeg_converted = frame2jpg(fb, 80, &_jpg_buf, &_jpg_buf_len);
          esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
          fb = NULL;
          if(!jpeg_converted){
            Serial.println("JPEG compression failed");
            res = ESP_FAIL;
          }
        } else {
          _jpg_buf_len = fb->len;
          _jpg_buf = fb->buf;
        }
      }
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      size_t hlen = snprintf((char *)part_buf, 64, _STREAM_PART, _jpg_buf_len);
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)part_buf, hlen);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, (const char *)_jpg_buf, _jpg_buf_len);
    }
    if(res == ESP_OK){
      res = httpd_resp_send_chunk(req, _STREAM_BOUNDARY, strlen(_STREAM_BOUNDARY));
    }
    if(fb){
      esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
      fb = NULL;
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    } else if(_jpg_buf){
      free(_jpg_buf);
      _jpg_buf = NULL;
    }
    if(res != ESP_OK){
      break;
    }
    //Serial.printf("MJPG: %uB\n",(uint32_t)(_jpg_buf_len));
  }
  return res;
}

void startCameraServer(){
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
  config.server_port = 80;

  httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
    .uri       = "/",
    .method    = HTTP_GET,
    .handler   = stream_handler,
    .user_ctx  = NULL
  };

  //Serial.printf("Starting web server on port: '%d'\n", config.server_port);
  if (httpd_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(stream_httpd, &index_uri);
  }
}

void setup() {
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0); //disable brownout detector
  // s1.setPeriodHertz(50);
  // s2.setPeriodHertz(50);
  // sn1.attach(2,1000,2000);
  // sn2.attach(13,1000,2000);
  // s1.attach(Ser_1,1000,2000);
  // s2.attach(Ser_2,1000,2000);
  // s1.write(pos1);
  // s2.write(pos2);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(false);

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;

  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
  // Wi-Fi connection
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  Serial.print("Camera Stream Ready! Go to: http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());

  // Start streaming web server
  startCameraServer();
}

void loop() {
  delay(1);
}
```

Now my question is: How to control GPIO pins on ESP32 Camera, from the python script, so that when an object is detected, ESP32-Cam can activate an alarm system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way you can use http request
when you detect something, while running the python app, you send a  **POST request**,  this link could help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313001/is-it-possible-to-make-post-request-in-flask

in the ESP32 you will receive the request since you have esp_http_server you must add a condition of what to do when you receive the request.